# Windows 7 and VirtualBox (centos 7) DNS not working

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, dns

I have a windows 7 host and an installation of virtualbox 5.1.4 (with centos 7 on top) for which I am struggling with due to connectivity issues.

I setup the VM with the following settings
[image]

And from my host I am able to ping it and also access it via ssh.

```
C:\Users\username>ping 10.13.81.75
Pinging 10.13.81.75 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.13.81.75: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.13.81.75: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Ping statistics for 10.13.81.75:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

My hosts file is setup as follows:

```
10.13.81.75 local.dev.com localhost
```

The domain is not working and cannot ping it, I get the following back

```
C:\Users\username>ping local.dev.com
Pinging local.dev.com [10.13.81.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.13.81.43: Destination host unreachable.
```

I know the domain is working from within the VB since I can ping it:

```
[root@local conf]# ping local.dev.com
PING local.dev.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from local.dev.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
64 bytes from local.dev.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from local.dev.com (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
```

Following other tuts and types of networks "attached to" lead me to the same problem, can ping / ssh but domains from the host are not working.
Any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a couple of hours, I found the answer in an unvoted answer in superuser:

Credit goes out to https://superuser.com/users/523684/george

> I also had this issue. From your description I was running the same set up as you. It turned out I had firewalld installed and was running and so had to use the commands:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer in here
https://superuser.com/a/1002470/636716